# What are the key shortcuts to comment and uncomment code?

Tags: visual-studio, comments, visual-studio-2012

There were <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (comment) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> (uncomment) in older versions, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>  and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.

But in Visual Studio 2012, I can't see key shortcuts:

[image]

How can I enable those shortcuts?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Keyboard accelerators are configurable.  You can find out which keyboard accelerators are bound to a command in menu *Tools* → *Options* on the *Environment* → *Keyboard* page.

These commands are named **Edit.CommentSelection** and **Edit.UncommentSelection**.

(With my settings, these are bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>.  I would guess that these are the defaults, at least in the C++ defaults, but I don't know for sure.  The best way to find out is to check your settings.)

Comment: Now it works for Ctrl+E, Ctrl+C and Ctrl+E, Ctrl+U for commenting and uncommenting respectively.

Answer (score 19):

You can also add the toolbar in Visual Studio to have the buttons available.

Menu *View* → *Toolbars* → *Text Editor*

[image]

Comment: I believe it is View -> Toolbars -> XML Editor if you are on an XML file, and then View -> Toolbars -> Text Editor if you are on a text file.  If you set one, it seems to remember it for both (so you should only have to set one).

Answer (score 13):

Use the keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>C</kbd> to comment out the line and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>U</kbd> to uncomment the line.

Answer (score 8):

From your screenshot it appears you have [ReSharper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#ReSharper_Ultimate) installed.

Depending on the key binding options you chose when you installed it, some of your standard shortcuts may now be redirected to ReSharper commands. It's worth checking, for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd> is used by ReSharper for the code cleanup dialog.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it,

Menu *Tools* → *Options on the Environment* → *Keyboard* window

One can alter the default shortcuts following the below steps

- Select **Edit.CommentSelection** in the listbox
- Click on "Remove" button
- Select "Text Editor" option in the dropdown under "Use new shortcut in:"
- Press your own shortcut in the textbox under "Press shortcut keys:"
  Example: Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and then <kbd>C</kbd> will give you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>
- Click on "Assign" button
- Repeat the same for **Edit.UnCommentSelection** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>U</kbd>)

Answer (score 1):

I went to menu: *Tools* → *Options*.

*Environment* → *Keyboard*.

Show command containing and searched: comment

I changed Edit.CommentSelection and assigned <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> for commenting.

And I left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>U</kbd> for the Edit.UncommentSelection.

These could be tweaked to the user's preference as to what key they would prefer for commenting/uncommenting.

Answer (score 0):

"commentLine" is the name of function you are looking for. This function comments and uncomments with the same keybinding.

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.

The command palette is great for finding shortcut keys.