# One keyboard shortcut ( Ctrl + / ) to comment or uncomment if commented in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Is there a way to use one keyboard shortcut ( Ctrl + / for example) to comment or uncomment if commented in Visual Studio 2012, like it is in SublimeText or PhpStorm?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066739/what-key-shortcuts-are-to-comment-and-uncomment-code-in-visual-studio-2012

Answer (score 0):

You could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for *comment* the selected and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> for *un-comment* the code lines. 
But remember this will add comment symbol (`//`) to all the code lines. As far as I know, there is no specific short cut for block comment (`/* .. */`) in VS 2012.