# Visual Studio 2012 Comment Shortcut in cshtml file

Tags: visual-studio, razor

I have a strange problem in that the Comment/Uncomment icons and shortcuts don't seem to active when I am editing a cshtml file but are active for other file types. This is in VS2012 using the MVC Single Page Application template.
Any help?
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check you configuration here: Tools -> Options on the Environment -> Keyboard.

Check this thread [What key shortcuts are to comment and uncomment code in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066739/what-key-shortcuts-are-to-comment-and-uncomment-code-in-visual-studio-2012)

Also if you have ReSharper installed you could try these [shortcuts Ctrl+/ and Ctrl+Shift+/](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Coding_Assistance__Comment_Uncomment_Code.html).

Comment: Thanks. But none of these approaches appear to work. What is strange is that it appears to only be a problem with .cshtml files in one project in one solution. In other projects and other solutions I don't have the problem. The project is the out the box MVC 4 Single Page Application. It appears as if some project setting is deactivating the comment/uncomment shortcut, icon and edit-advanced menu option.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a helpful extension to manage your visual studio shortcuts. This extension will helps you to available shortcuts in current environment

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f2964c90-68e2-4ddd-861a-bd66e5cd4434